# How to get databases in cpanel phpMyAdmin version to show up in localhost version of phpMyAdmin on WAMP server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I use inmotionhosting for my websites and databases. I have a specific database that I created in mysql and then built the tables via the cpanel version of phpMyAdmin.

I found out that the cpanel version of phpMyAdmin does not have priviliges or user controls so I installed WAMP server and installed phpMyAdmin on it. I can log into it as root user and everything seems to be configured correctly.

How do I make the databases that I created in the cpanel version of phpMyAdmin show up in the phpMyAdmin that I installed on my WAMP server?

I have done countless web and document searches and cannot find an answer for what exactly I need to do to fix this problem. I need assistance. Please and Thank you!

Comment: I assume you installed WAMPServer on your PC, right?

Comment: Does inmotionhosting allow you to remotely access a database on their server. 1) at all? 2) after creating a user account with remote access?

Comment: Yes I have installed WAMP server on my PC and yes I can access it because I have the database connected to a website that I am using and that connection works fine. The process of accessing it with WAMP server via phpMyAdmin is what I do not understand and cannot find literature to assist me through it.

Comment: It might be simpler to just install MYSQL WorkBench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the following way. I accessed the config.inc.php file and changed this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

I changed it to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[my server's static IP address]';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

I was then able to login as any user that was previously made or assigned to this database in MySQL and the appropriate database showed up.

Comment: I am getting error as Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '....'@'localhost' (using password: YES)